# How to create index with concatenating two columns in Procedure/Function using pl/sql

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle19c

I want to create index of concatenating two columns, using this query:

```
   declare 
   t_name varchar(100) := upper('test');
   table_space varchar(100) := 'users';
   begin
   execute immediate 
           'create index ' || upper('trx_cst_indx') || ' ON ' || t_name || '(' || trx_date||'_'||customer_id || ') local unusable';
   end;
```

Running that query gives me this error:

```
 PLS-00201: identifier 'TRX_DATE' must be declared
 ORA-06550: line 5, column 16:
 PL/SQL: Statement ignored
 06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
 *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
```

Then I use single quotation for the column names like this:

```
 declare 
 t_name varchar(100) := upper('test_etl');
 table_space varchar(100) := 'users';
 begin
 execute immediate 
           'create index ' || upper('trx_cst_indx') || ' ON ' || t_name || '(' || 'trx_date'||'_'||'customer_id' || ') local unusable';
 end;
```

While running the above query, I receive this error:

```
 Error report - ORA-00904: "TRX_DATE_CUSTOMER_ID": invalid identifier
 ORA-06512: at line 5
 00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
 *Cause:
```

I don't know what is wrong with these queries.
Would you please guide me how to create index with concatenating two columns in this mode?

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: 'create index trx_cst_indx ON '| | t_name || ' (trx_date,customer_id) local unusable';

Comment: In the answer to your previous question ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72799983/266304)) you were advised to construct and print the statement before executing it so you could see what is actually being run. You don't seem to have done that.

Comment: @AlexPoole, I do display my query, this question is about how to create index of concatenating of two columns in the procedure/function.

Comment: As @OldProgrammer Mentioned in the first comment, you need to put,(comma) in place of _.  There is nothing like concatenating two columns, you can create composite index using multiple columns.

Comment: @MansiRaval, yeah OldProgrammer's comment solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
'create index trx_cst_indx ON '| | t_name || ' (trx_date,customer_id) local unusable';
```